# Google map reviews_average and reviews_count scraped issue

Tags: python, windows, xcode, dictionary

i am tried to scrape google map but i faced a problem when i tried to scrape reviews count and reviews average its scrape only first 4 out of total scraped: 8

```
 for index in range(min(total, len(listings))):
            try:
                listings[index].click()
                page.wait_for_timeout(8000)
            except playwright._impl._api_types.Error as e:
                print(f"Error clicking on listing {index + 1}: {e}")
                continue

            name_xpath = f'(//div[contains(@class, "qBF1Pd fontHeadlineSmall ")])[{index + 1}]'
            address_xpath = '//button[@data-item-id="address"]//div[contains(@class, "fontBodyMedium")]'
            website_xpath = '//a[@data-item-id="authority"]//div[contains(@class, "fontBodyMedium")]'
            phone_number_xpath = '//button[contains(@data-item-id, "phone:tel:")]//div[contains(@class, "fontBodyMedium")]'
            category_xpath = '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/span/button'
            reviews_span_xpath = f'//div[{index + 1}]//span[@role="img"]'
            
           
            business = Business()

            if page.locator(name_xpath).count() > 0:
                business.name = page.locator(name_xpath).inner_text()
            else:
                business.name = "N/A"

            if page.locator(address_xpath).count() > 0:
                business.address = page.locator(address_xpath).inner_text()
            else:
                business.address = "N/A"

            if page.locator(website_xpath).count() > 0:
                business.website = page.locator(website_xpath).inner_text()
            else:
                business.website = "N/A"

            if page.locator(phone_number_xpath).count() > 0:
                business.phone_number = page.locator(phone_number_xpath).inner_text()
            else:
                business.phone_number = "N/A"

            if page.locator(category_xpath).count() > 0:
                business.category = page.locator(category_xpath).inner_text()
            else:
                business.category = "N/A"

            page.mouse.wheel(0, 20000)
            page.wait_for_timeout(1000)
            reviews_elements = listings[index].locator(reviews_span_xpath)  # Move this line inside the loop
            if reviews_elements.count() > 0:
                reviews_label = reviews_elements.nth(0).get_attribute("aria-label")
                print(f"Reviews Label: {reviews_label}")

                # Process the reviews label to extract count and average
                # Example processing using regular expressions
                import re
                match = re.match(r'([\d.]+) stars ([\d,]+) Reviews', reviews_label)

                if match:
                    reviews_average = float(match.group(1))
                    reviews_count = int(re.sub(',', '', match.group(2)))
                else:
                    reviews_average = None
                    reviews_count = None

                # Update the Business object with reviews information
                business.reviews_average = reviews_average
                business.reviews_count = reviews_count
            else:
                business.reviews_average = None
                business.reviews_count = None
```

Output is:

Total Scraped: 8

Reviews Label: 4.6 stars 117 Reviews

Reviews Label: 5.0 stars 1 Reviews

Reviews Label: 4.6 stars 1,308 Reviews

Reviews Label: 4.9 stars 1,021 Reviews

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwFOm.png)

Kindly help in this

Answer (score 0):

hoping this will help. I suggest trying [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/) and using its webdriver .find_element or .find_elements(By.XPATH, "XPATHInDoubleQuotes"), .click(), etc functions to navigate and interact with the website. Selenium should allow you to easily understand what is going on by opening the browser and doing things you can watch and follow. In addition to that, relative XPATH or CLASS name should be recommended as XPATH may vary from time to time making the code less dynamic.
P.S. Use time.sleep() or Selenium's WebDriverWait to make sure pages load properly.